# Selenium, Cucumber and Java in IntelliJ: Replace Junit with TestNG

Tags: selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, junit, cucumber, testng

I've got a large Maven project with an e2e-testing project included. The project and architecture is not created by me, but I've been using it for a while.

The project uses Cucumber for .feature files, and Java test definition files. Then an architecture of PO-objects and other classes "below" that.

Now, I'm sure the project uses Junit. But since I'm only working with the Selenium tests and not any unit or api tests, I'm not too sure about the underlying architecture.

My test runner file apparently uses JUnit:

```
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import e2e.support.Hooks;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import java.util.Set;

@Slf4j
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    plugin   = { "pretty", "json:target/cucumber.json", "html:target/cucumber-html-report" },
    tags = { "~@integrasjon", "~@Ignore", "~@ToggledOff", "~@Kjent_feil" },
    features = { "src/test/resources/features" })
```

public class CucumberTest {

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setup() {

...and so on...
```

It possible to replace Junit as a test runner for the Cucumber/Selenium tests?

I've added the Maven dependencies in the pom.xml file for the e2e-test project. But since the only thing I do when running tests manually is select "Run" or "Debug" from the Cucumber feature file, I'm in the dark with regards to the connections between that and Junit/TestNG.

All hints or pointers are appreciated. I've found some help online, but that was an example of creating a new project - and in Eclipse - which made it a bit difficult to identify exactly what I need to pick.

Comment: Is there some reason you want to replace JUnit with TestNG? Seems like a lot of work for probably little benefit unless you are having a specific problem with JUnit.

Comment: A bit more long-term. It seems that implementing functionality to automatically rerun failed tests is easier when using TestNG tha JUnit.